Add a domain to whitelist for DNSBL check on SpamAssassin
I'm trying to tell SpamAssassin (vX) to not test the DNSBL of a specific domain, but I can't find the proper value in the local.cf file.
I have tried the following:
trusted_networks mydomain.com # I believe it's only IPs, but I tested nonetheless
whitelist_from mydomain.com
whitelist_from_rcvd mydomain.com
dns_query_restriction deny mydomain.com

I tried all of these, but despite them, when running a test, I still get the following :
$> spamassassin -t -D < myemail.eml
...
Apr 22 09:26:26.094 [2129173] dbg: async: timing: 0.029 . askdns:A:mydomain.com.lookup.dkimwl.org
...
Apr 22 09:26:26.096 [2129173] dbg: async: timing: 0.049 . DNSBL:mydomain.com:dbl.spamhaus.org
Apr 22 09:26:26.096 [2129173] dbg: async: timing: 0.049 . DNSBL:mydomain.com:bl.score.senderscore.com
...
Apr 22 09:26:26.097 [2129173] dbg: async: timing: 0.062 . DNSBL:mydomain.com:multi.uribl.com
...
Apr 22 09:26:26.097 [2129173] dbg: async: timing: 0.094 . DNSBL:mydomain.com:sa-accredit.habeas.com
Apr 22 09:26:26.097 [2129173] dbg: async: timing: 0.096 . DNSBL:mydomain.com:sa-trusted.bondedsender.org
...
Apr 22 09:26:26.097 [2129173] dbg: async: timing: 0.106 . DNSBL:mydomain.com:multi.surbl.org
...
Apr 22 09:26:26.098 [2129173] dbg: async: timing: 0.281 . DNSBL:mydomain.com:dob.sibl.support-intelligence.net
...

What parameter can I set to SA to tell to never DNS query a given domain?

Is there a domain you always want Spamassassin to not be spam?

I'd like to tell SpamAssassin to never run DNS checks (DNSBL, etc) on a given domain
